# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- relevant blogs and websites about computer science
- computer science events, conferences, or meetups
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1452).

Answer (score 11):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [From TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/community-promotion-ads-2016/6493#6493), same as [last year](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1372)

Answer (score 8):

[image: arXiv.org]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Quantum Computing Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: We'd be happy to welcome you!]

Answer (score 6):

[image: A curated list of answers that go over the basics in detail!]

Comment: "If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it." I think you need to add a border; I'm having a hard time knowing where the edges are.

Comment: IMO this doesn't effectively communicate what it's about. I saw it in the sidebar and thought it was a link to an FAQ about how StackExchange works.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have a hard time reading the ad like that. Still, do you have a proposal for different  text that avoids the misassociation?

Comment: @Raphael, maybe I was primed by having recently been browsing a meta site. Anyway, changing "*basics*" to "*basics of CS*" would make it clear that it's not about the basics of Stack Exchange. I can't think of any clear name for "reference questions".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Then maybe simply "CS basics" instead of "the basics"?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: [From last year](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1375/98).

Answer (score 1):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Review queues]

Comment: Heh, this has to be upgraded, doesn't it? Will get on that soon. I hope.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Computer Science Chat]

Comment: +1, thx for posting but feel the blandness of the image does not strongly compel/ drive clickthrus, believe that clickthrus to chat could be increased with more drama/ info. & CS chat is very low activity lately so hope a compelling ad could successfully combat/ overcome the general _low energy/ inactivity_ :|

Comment: @vzn maybe, but the picked colors are compatible with site design, and old cool books (hope you know what I mean), I am not really into shouty ads, they tend to be ignored, simply because they attract attention in unplesant way. If this ad will not hit the threshold, I will think about something sharper.

Answer (score 1):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score -1):

[image: Turing Machine blog]

Comment: I don't think linking personal blogs here is appropriate. Community ads should demonstrably be relevant to a large fraction of the community.

Comment: :( its chock full of CS related content, copious refs/ links back to stackexchange by a longtime loyalist/ committed user, etc., it was accepted in 2017, etc

Comment: I note that in 2016, the ad linked to [chat]. IIRC you created the image when we collected ideas on how best to link to chat. In 2017, the same image pointed to your blog (without notice or explanation). While I don't know the extent, I think it's fair to assume that people voted assuming it was the same ad as the year before. (I know *I* didn't realize the change of target until that comment appeared.)

Comment: think people voted exactly according to their opinion & with full information (a comment below the image long indicated it was my blog). decided in 2017 to change the image location after another image/ entry was added by `Evil` to point to the chat. the official guidelines allow, even _encourage_ blogs. most blogs are "personal" in nature. the blog also has fully open comments & encourage _discussion_ there, which is expressly _discouraged_ on SE etc... & allow controversial topics of known interest to CS users but restricted on SE eg P vs NP proofs etc! so its all a feature, not a bug :)

Answer (score -1):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Computer Science Stack Exchange on Twitter]

Comment: From [last year](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1378/98).